# Is there any Laravel way to execute a .SQL file to load data

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have historical data that I want to load in new DB.

I could do it by running MySQL command but I am interested to know whether there are `artisan` commands to do it?

Answer (score 22):

There isn't a way to import a DB dump out-of-the-box using `artisan`.  However, you could create a custom `artisan` command:

`php artisan make:console DbImportCommand`

and then have it issue a command like:

`DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('full/path/to/dump.sql'));`

However, it may be advantageous to create a command that runs a seeder (or set of seeders).

`php artisan make:console importHistoricalData`

and then have that run specific seeders:

```
$this->call(OldCompanySeeder::class);
$this->call(OldEmployeeSeeder::class);
// etc....
```

If you wipe the database at some point, or move to a new environment, it's as simple as just running the seeders again.

Comment: I do know about seeder but here I am importing thousands of records.

Comment: Then my first suggestion may be more appropriate.  You can also take a look at Seeders here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding