# Laravel migration - is it possible to use SQL instead of schema commands to create tables and fields etc?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, migration

We have an existing complex database schema complete with indexes, constraints, triggers, tables etc.

With liquibase, you can point to pure sql files in your changesets, which could be a dump of the whole DB for the first (initial schema creation) migration.

Is there any way to do this with the laravel artisan migration system?

We would like to do all our db updates using the SQL language (because we know it already, and because we will only ever user mysql), but need the framework (migrate or liquibase) to apply the changes in the right order etc. (so they keep a log on the DB of the changes already applied etc).

If not, has anyone used liqubase with laravel?  The only issue is that it wont be able to read the .env db connection strings, and that each developer will need to install liqubase (not the end of the world, but if the laravel built in system can use sql, it would save us time and effort)

Comment: Thanks Leo. I know we can manually create the schema (we are doing this now), but for automated deployment, it would be great to use one tool e.g. artisan migrate, or liquidise, to do the database creation/updating.   Also, we would want to do the additional migrations using sql, and use the migration framwork just to manage the order.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, it is possible to create migrations which use raw SQL

You are not limited to what code you can run in your migrations. [Run raw SQL queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) using the DB facade. This example shows both methods being used in the same migration.

```
class AddColumnsToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('age');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::update('update users set age = 30 where name = ?', ['John']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So could I write a function which reads in a specified SQL file and executes it as a script (not a single statement)?  DB::update would not work in this case as I would be passing in a long set of statements including create table, create index, drop tables, create columns etc.  This is what we need to processs a dump of the DB and similar sql script files.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any reason why you could not do that. However is that a particular reason you want to do that versus using Laravel to do it for you? In my experience it ends up being much more concise and easier to read than raw SQL.

Comment: I have a 400 table SQL dump of the DB - to convert this from the existing SQL format to Schema commands would take days, and there is probably not a 1 to 1 mapping + a lot of room for errors.  At the end of the day, we know SQL and Mysql, we dont know the language used by laravel to create SQL.  Looks like the way to go is liquibase, if Migration is not designed to be used with raw SQL Scripts (as opposed to raw SQL commands).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831862/is-there-any-laravel-way-to-execute-a-sql-file-to-load-data

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are plenty of benefits of using raw / plain SQL migrations in certain cases

- complex schema(s),
- taking advantage of vendor specific extensions to SQL (both DDL and DML)
- richer / additional data types
- using vendor specific procedural code (i.e. PL/pgSQL anonymous blocks in PostgreSQL)
- etc

Although there is a way to execute raw SQL in Laravel migrations, writing and managing raw SQL code in variables even with `heredoc` is painful and unnatural.

*Full disclaimer: here goes a shameless plug*

Recently I've created an experimental package [laravel-sql-migrations](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/laravel-sql-migrations) that I use in my projects to abstract the details of raw SQL execution and allow for writing and keeping SQL migrations in `*.sql` files almost like in Liquibase or Flyway.

The package among other things extends `make:migration` and `make:model` commands so that you can use a familiar workflow

```bash
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --sql
```

or

```bash
php artisan make:model User --migration --sql
```

which will produce three files

```
database
└── migrations
    ├── 2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.down.sql
    ├── 2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.php
    └── 2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.up.sql
```

At this point you can forget about `2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.php` unless you want to configure or override behavior of this particular migration (i.e. set a specific connection and / or make use of transactions if your database supports them for DDL i.e. PostgreSQL).

If you don't use reverse / down migrations you can delete the corresponding `*.down.sql` file.

Here is how migrations for the standard Laravel `users` table might look like if you  were to use PostgreSQL

```sql
-- 2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.up.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name CITEXT,
    email CITEXT,
    password TEXT,
    remember_token TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS users_email_idx ON users (email);
```

```sql
-- 2018_06_15_000000_create_users_table.down.sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
```

Comment: Good job, I'm working on a mal-maintained Laravel project. This is helping me to put all existing migrations in one. And now I can start fresh!